# use rm linux order in execl() function ic C language

Tags: c, linux, rm, execl

hope to be fine...
i'm trying write code that use execl within execl in C language but it's not working when i put the directory of file.
the code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
 int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
  int n,m,x;
  n=fork();
  if(n==0){
     execl("/bin/rm","rm /home/mazenas/Desktop/folder/","f.txt",NULL);
          }
  else{
     wait(&m);
     printf("end of Programm\n");
      }
  return 0;
  }
```

help me plaese!

Answer (score 5):

The arguments of [`execl()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) is specifying the command-line arguments of the program to be executed.

```
execl("/bin/rm","rm /home/mazenas/Desktop/folder/","f.txt",NULL);
```

means to execute this:

```
"rm /home/mazenas/Desktop/folder/" "f.txt"
```

If you want to execute this command:

```
rm "/home/mazenas/Desktop/folder/f.txt"
```

You should write:

```
execl("/bin/rm", "rm", "/home/mazenas/Desktop/folder/f.txt", NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you mean

```
 execl("/bin/rm","rm", "/home/mazenas/Desktop/folder/f.txt",NULL);
```

If `rm` checks its invocation name, then `f.txt` makes no sense and it complains; otherwise it's going to try to rm `f.txt` in the current directory rather than the given path.